# For Dokuwiki how can I make an image be a link and have a caption at the same time?

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm migrating from MediaWiki to Dokuwiki, because I can't get MediaWiki to work anymore. I've got most of the things how I want it and how I had it from MediaWiki, but I can't figure out how to make an image a link and have a caption. I know how to do them separately, but I can't figure out how to make them work together. At best, make the caption the link, but that's not what I want. I have the Imagebox Plugin for the caption, but nothing I do works. If seen some people say use {{image.png|caption}} but these were older, and it seems the current version cant do it, unless I don't have a feature enabled or something. I've tried different configurations but nothing works. Is this even possible in Dokuwiki or is there a code I'm not using, or do I need a different plugin?

An image as a link and with caption.